# Having issues with Infragistics column resizing

Tags: winforms, datagrid, infragistics

I have a grid and I would like to automatically resize the columns. I'm running into inconsistencies when using different parameter values for PerformAutoResize(). When passing in the values below, where the *true* means include column headers:

```
PerformAutoResize(PerformAutoSizeType.VisibleRows, true);
```

some columns will be resized based solely on the header, while others will resize properly based on both the header and the row values.

However, if I hardcode in a value:

```
PerformAutoResize(20);
```

It works fine for every column.

Why is this?

**UPDATE**

Through some trial and error I've come to the conclusion that I think the issue is that I bring in the data and then have it auto-sort by a certain row. When using a hard coded value, it appears to auto-size the columns after that initial auto-sort, whereas when I use PerformAutoSizeType.VisibleRows it appears to auto-size the columns before the initial auto-sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [PerformAutoResize](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~PerformAutoResize%28PerformAutoSizeType,Boolean%29.html)([PerformAutoSizeType](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PerformAutoSizeType.html).AllRowsInBand, true); give you the results that you are looking for?

If so then is it possible that when you make the call that the row that you want to size the grid by isn't visible?

Comment: That does work (although it takes quite a while). Through some trial and error I came to the same conclusion you suggested. I think the issue is that I bring in the data and then have it auto-sort by a certain row. When using a hard coded value, it appears to auto-size the columns after that initial auto-sort, whereas when I use PerformAutoSizeType.VisibleRows it appears to auto-size the columns before the initial auto-sort.

Comment: What event are you setting the sorting and calling PerformAutoResize?  Also if you are doing this in InitializeLayout, where are you setting the DataSource?

Comment: It's in InitializeLayout and the DataSource is being set in the load event of the form.

Comment: Warning, using that method the grid will be re-bound to data and call initialise_row on all rows - which can cause a cascade. Use with caution